# Extract all date components from a Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

(I was surprised that I could not find this question asked anywhere, it sounds so basic. I might be missing something...)

**Is there a way to create a DateComponents() object that exactly matches a Date/NSDate object (date, time, calendar, timeZone), without having to specify all the components we want to include?**

*Example of a concrete use case*: the UNCalendarNotificationTrigger init method takes DateComponents as an argument, and we'd like to set that notification to a specific date and time kept as a Date/NSDate object, whose dateComponents we therefore need to extract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Calendar.dateComponents(in:,from:)` to achieve your goals. This way you only need to supply the `TimeZone` and can extract all `DateComponents` from a `Date` object.

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: Date())
```

Comment: Fantastic Dávid, I had seen this method and for whatever reason that I do not remember, had doubts that this would do exactly what was needed. Thank you